# modprobe fails to insert beegfs after installing mellanox drivers

Tags: kernel-module, mellanox, beegfs

I have a storage cluster that has been churning along for a few years. It's based around a pretty stock Centos 7.6 setup, using beegfs.

In an effort to increase throughput I've decided to do a test-upgrade of the network, from 10gig to 40gig. However, it would appear that the necessary drivers for this 40gig card conflicts with beegfs in terms of kernel modules. Now that I have the 40gig network running successfully, beegfs-client fails to start:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'beegfs': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

How do I make these two get along?

The cards I've installed are all ConnectX-3 FDR Infiniband (both ports configured to Ethernet, though). The driver I installed is `MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.0-2.1.8.0-rhel7.6-x86_64`. Uninstalling the driver did not resolve the issue, but the 40gig network is still working. It was only needed for recorfiguring the ports to Ethernet instead of Infiniband.

**Update:** From the looks of it, I will need to add infiniband support to the `beegfs-client-autobuild.conf`. Not entirely sure where to find the source that I need to reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simpler than anticipated: upgrade to the newest version of beegfs-client. The newer version includes infiniband compatibility by default. No rebuild needed.

After an upgrade and a reboot, the cluster behaved as intended again, with the Mellanox 40Gb/s cards operating.